# Combine first pandas but keeping columns name in new column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe with the following form:

```
  V1    V2
0 10.0  NaN
1 NaN   15.0
2 5.0   NaN
3 NaN   10.0
```

and I want to combine columns `V1` and `V2` and have the result be

```
  V    column_name
0 10.0 V1  
1 15.0 V2   
2 5.0  V1   
3 10.0 V2
```

I have tried pandas.combine_first but I can't reach an optimal solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
res = (df
       .stack()
       .reset_index(level=1)
       .set_axis(["column_name", "V"], axis=1)
       )
```

This should output :

```
  column_name     V
0          V1  10.0
1          V2  15.0
2          V1   5.0
3          V2  10.0
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to do a `df.stack()`. This is my example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({"V1":[10, np.nan, 5, np.nan], "V2":[np.nan, 15, np.nan, 10]})
df = df.stack()
```

Output:

```
0  V1    10.0
1  V2    15.0
2  V1     5.0
3  V2    10.0
dtype: float64
```

Be careful, the output is a Series object, so you should cast it to assign column names.